# How are redirect loops detected by browsers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, browser

If page `A` redirects to `B` and `B` redirects to `A`.

```
A → B
B → A
```

Then, obviously this is a redirect loop. What I'm not sure is: is the browser just checking if the redirect page was accessed before and if it was it declares it a redirect loop or there are some other things going on?

This would be helpful to know in the context of a Node.js module which follows the redirects and should be able to detect such redirect loops.

Comment: So you want to know how browser is working internally?

Comment: The *basic* idea behind this functionality is to simply check if this web-site is not going to show you the requested page, but will redirect you forever. At the same time, implementation (including algorithm, redirects count limit etc.) vary from browser to browser.

Comment: @Justinas Yes, would be also curious if there are different implementations.

Comment: I think it's obvious, that all browsers does not copy-paste same algorithm...

Comment: At least I'd be curious to see what popular browsers do (e.g. Chromium and Firefox since their source is available)—I'm not a C/C++ hacker tho...